# How to say "Big families" in English?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there any appropriate phrase to say "big families"? included my own family (father, mother), my aunt's family, my uncle's family, grandma, grandpa etc.?

Comment: So, how will you use that "extended family", example when you want to tell someone that, the whole "big family" attended the party. Can I say: "Our whole extended family attended John's wedding"?

Answer (score 5):

"Extended family" should work for you.

Comment: Just to expand on this correct answer, *extended family* is the accepted English term for a family grouping including more than just the parents and their children (which is known as the *nuclear family*).